# Android shared preference when activity recreated

Tags: android, android-edittext, sharedpreferences

Hi in my app i am using two themes.
When there is theme change, the activity will be recreated. At this point I am unable to restore the edit text values.

```
      @Override
        protected void onResume() {


            SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(
                    Constants.PREFERENCE_FILENAME, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

            edt_kilo.setText(mSharedPreferences.getString(Constants.KILO_VAL,""));
            edt_pound.setText(mSharedPreferences.getString(Constants.POUND_VAL,""));

            if ((edt_centimeter.getText().toString().length() > 0)
                    || (edt_feet.getText().toString().length() > 0)
                    || (edt_inches.getText().toString().length() > 0)) {
                imagelayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                super.onResume();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();

            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = mSharedPref.edit();
            edit.putString(Constants.KILO_VAL, edt_kilo.getText().toString());
edit.putString(Constants.POUND_VAL,edt_pound.getText().toString());

            edit.commit();

        }

    @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {

                this.finish();
        }
```

The problem with the above code is even after finishing the activity by pressing device's "back" button, the values are still preserved, which I don't want.

Also when I "clear" the value from the edittext and when I press device's "back" button and when I come again the same value are still there.

How to handle this condition

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity{

    private String etFirstValue="";
    private String etSecondValue="";
    private EditText etTwo,etOne;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //initaialize views here
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        etFirstValue = savedInstanceState.getString("firstEditTextKey");
        etSecondValue = savedInstanceState.getString("secondEditTextKey");
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putString("firstEditTextKey", "value");
        outState.putString("secondEditTextKey", "value");
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //set the values to edit text
        etOne.setText(etFirstValue);
        etTwo.setText(etFirstValue);

    }

}
```

for brief explaination you can go through this link:[here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)

Comment: i used your method, but when i change the theme, the values are not coming in respective edittext

Comment: what you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are setting the values from shared preferences and shared preferences does not get cleared when activity of app is closed and opened.

you can either the clear the preferences if you can or set the null values to the edit text in onStop().

Comment: i tried both setting null values and clearing the shared preference in onStop() method, but when activty is getting recreated the vales should stay ..but itz not happenibng